# Codeigniter caching the same method with other parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I´m working on caching in Codeigniter and I find out one problem which I don´t know how to solve:
I have method view_produdcts() where I get products according the url and render the view. I turned on the cache there but if I want to render product´s with some parameters for the first time, it´s ok, but if I try to render another products with other parameters, it still returns me the products which I loaded for the first time.

Do you know, how to solve it?

Thank you very much for your ideas.

Here is my method:

```
/**
 * view products by parameters
 */
    public function view_products()
{  
    $limit = 12; // limit of products per page
    $attrs = parse_attributes_from_url($_GET); // load attributes from url

    $config['per_page'] = $limit; // set some config files for paging
    $config['base_url'] = prepare_url_from_attributes_for_paging(generate_url_from_attributes($attrs));
    $config['cur_page'] = $attrs['page'];

    $attrs['limit'] = $limit;

    $data['products'] = $this->products_model->get_products_specified($attrs); products
    $data['popular_categories'] = $this->categories_model->get_popular_categories();
    $data['all_categories'] = $this->categories_model->get_categories_list_eshop();

    if(isset($attrs['cat']) && $attrs['cat'] != null){
    $data['category_title'] = $this->categories_model->get_category_title($attrs['cat']);
    }
    else {
    $data['category_title'] = $this->categories_model->get_category_title(3);    
    }
    main_view_front('products/category', $data);
}
```

Comment: Use smart cache library for CodeIgniter. https://github.com/msnisha/smart-cache

Comment: Thank you.
On which depends the cache file created for CI?
Because, I have another method - view with parameters $slug and $id and I render there the view of the product and I use cache there too and there this problem isn´t - everytime it shows me the right view, not still the same

Comment: CI cache is for the URI, when the URL changes due to parameter change then there is a new cache for these. But only issue with CI cache is you don't have an option to execute something inside the controller method the output is cache. Smart Cache provide option to execute something then output from cache.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my system of links so I don´t need to use smart cache.